# Showing $E[\|x\|^2xx']=\text{tr}(\Sigma)\Sigma+2\Sigma^2$

Tags: normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Empirically the following seems to hold for $x \sim \text{Normal}(0, \Sigma)$, any idea how to show this rigorously?

$$E[\|x\|^2xx']=\text{tr}(\Sigma)\Sigma+2\Sigma^2$$

Comment: Start with $\Sigma$ diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with $\Sigma$ diagonal the result is also diagonal and $i,i$th entry of that matrix is 
$$E[\|x\|^2 x_i^2]=\sum_j E[x_i^2 x_j^2]$$
The $i$th term of that sum is Gaussian 4-th moment, so $3\sigma_i^2$ while remaining terms factor as $\sigma_i \sigma_j$ because of independence. Rearranging we get

$$E[\|x\|^2 x_i^2]=\text{tr}(\Sigma) \sigma_i  + 2\sigma_i^2  $$

Comment: Good!  Now, using the representation $\Sigma=U\Delta U$ for orthogonal $U$ and diagonal $\Delta$, handle the general case as well.  (Using  $\|y\|=\|Uy\|$, of course.)

Comment: or just "sigma is diagonal WLOG" :)